# SAPUI5 Filter column based on formatted data

Tags: xml, sapui5

Currently I have some columns in the table that have their values passed through a formatter, eg. a value is changed to a corresponding string from the 18n file. Sorting the content of the respective column based on the unformatted value appears to work but filtering using the formatted string does not. Filtering only works when the original value is entered. This is predictably the value used for the filter and sorting properties.

Before realizing the problem I tinkered with filterType in the XML without success. Is there a simple way I'm overlooking to have the filter respect the formatted value?